# Add to cart validation based on category and custom textfield in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, categories

I am using WooCommerce and add two new fields in product page, when I want to validate with `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` it works perfect.

But it turns out that I only want those fields in products that contain a specific category.

The fields show only in '`flower-arrangements`' category, so I just want the validation to apply when the fields are shown.

I have this:

```php
function garo_validate_custom_field( $passed ) {
    global $post;

     if (is_product() && has_term( 'flower-arrangements', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ) {  
     if( empty( $_POST['text_flowers_label'] ) ) {
     wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a value into the text flowers label', 'cfwc' ), 'error' );
     $passed = false;
     echo "<script>alert('hola');</script>";
     }
     return $passed;
  }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'garo_validate_custom_field', 10 );
```

---

And directly the conditional does not work, I have tried several options and nothing. The result is that nothing is added to the cart. What I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook contains not one but 5 parameters
- Use `wc_add_notice` opposite `<script>alert('hola');</script>`

So you get

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Set (multiple) categories
    $categories = array ( 'flower-arrangements', 'categorie-1' );
    
    // If passed & has_term
    if ( $passed && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        // Field is empty
        if( empty( $_POST['text_flowers_label'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a value into the text flowers label', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            $passed = false;
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Genius! It worked perfectly for me. It was not close to reaching the solution, I never imagined that $ passed was used in the if. I was left with the doubt, try to change $ passed by is_product in the conditional, however this does not work. Why does it work with $ passed? Thank you!

Comment: **1)** `Is_product` - Returns true on a single product page. However, you also have add to cart buttons on the archive pages. **2)** make sure there is always at least 1 `return` in the function without a condition having to be fulfilled. 
Otherwise, it may happen that `return` is never reached.